# installing scipy version 1.1.0

Tags: python, scipy

I need to install `scipy` version 1.1.0.
After I run the command `pip install scipy==1.1.0`, I get the following error:

```
Collecting scipy==1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.1.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for scipy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: scipy
    Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n02rqpmt\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n02rqpmt\\scipy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qa6zm3ga\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\scipy'
         cwd: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n02rqpmt\scipy\
    Complete output (147 lines):

Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)
```

help me please

Comment: "Using legacy 'setup.py install' for scipy, since package 'wheel' is not installed." - try running `pip install wheel` before you install scipy.

Comment: what commands should I use ? @SpiderPig1297

Comment: Try `pip install wheel` and then `pip install scipy==1.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

You must first install the Python version compatible with scipy.
I could not use pip to install scipy version 1.1 [ I think this version is no longer supported on pip] and used conda instead:

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy==1.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using pip make sure that, of python2 is installed. or else try with the python3

`pip install scipy==1.1.0` for python

`pip3 install scipy==1.1.0` for python3

it will install successfully

```
pip install scipy==1.1.0
Collecting scipy==1.1.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/f3/de9c1bd16311982711209edaa8c6caa962db30ebb6a8cc6f1dcd2d3ef616/scipy-1.1.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (30.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 30.8MB 36kB/s 
Collecting numpy>=1.8.2 (from scipy==1.1.0)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/5f/47e578b3ae79e2624e205445ab77a1848acdaa2929a00eeef6b16eaaeb20/numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.0MB 67kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy, scipy
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.6 scipy-1.1.0
```